# C# Projects and Config Files

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pull some key/values in my class.  This is a C# Class Library Project (not web project) so it's got an App.Config.

In my C# Project (Class Library), got the following:

1) **A utility method to pull a key/value from a config file:**

```
public class ConfigUtil
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Utility method to retrieve configuration setting values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configKey">Configuration Settings key to retrieve.</param>
    /// <returns>empty string if key is null</returns>
    public static string GetAppConfigSetting(string configKey)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey] ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This utility method was used in a web project and I just copied and pasted this nice helper into my C# Project because I need these auth and end points for authing to a third party API in some code in my C# Project.

2) **A Config.cs to hold my lookups**

```
class Config
{
    public static string SomeThirdPartyApiEndpoint
    {
        get { return ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("SomeThirdPartyApiEndpoint"); }
    }

    public static string SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername
    {
        get { return ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername"); }
    }

    public static string SomeThirdPartyApiAuthPassword
    {
        get { return ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("SomeThirdPartyApiAuthPassword"); }
    }
}
```

3) **In my App.Config, the key/values:**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomeThirdPartyApiEndPoint" value="http://someEndPointUrl.com/XMLAPI" />
    <add key="SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername" value="someUserNameHere" />
    <add key="SomeThirdPartyApiAuthPassword" value="5233s54" />
  </appSettings>
```

4) **Some example code in one of my classes in this project trying to pull one of the key values:**

```
string password = Config.SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername;
```

this line is in one of my class methods.

**The problem**: it's not finding any of my key/values.  When I debug, I get an empty string for password.

I assume I'm doing this right in that these key/values need to be put in my App.Config since I do not have a web.config since this is not a Web Project.  This is a wrapper project I am creating to wrap calls to a third party API.

**Another question related**: So then would then ConfigurationManager.AppSettings look for an App.Config if a Web.config is not present?  I am wondering how this ConfigurationManager pulls...does it look for only web.configs or any .config available in the immediate project?

Comment: The related question is confusing...is this a web project or a windows project? ...ASP.NET projects get their settings from the web.config...

Comment: just a C# project...plain Class Library Project

Comment: ok, then I'm __guessing__ that depending on the environment it's deployed in, it will use the configuration file available.  You should test it, since it wouldn't take long to create the sample projects.  Also, please check out my solution :)

Comment: Updated to fix the SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername...that is consistent now

Comment: Yea in fact that's what I'm trying to do is test it.  So I created a Test project (another C# class library project).  Then referenced this project in my test project.  Started to run some tests..it hit that line of code you see above in my main project...and it can't find those strings in whatever .config it's trying to look for.  So maybe I need to add a config file to my test project..like an App.config or something and move the strings to there?  Sorry, I'm a bit new to testing.

Comment: @CoffeeAddicct -- now I'm confused...I thought these were all ready in an App.Config file?

Comment: skyrim you are right.  I had to add the strings in the consuming project using this one.  Thanks.  I guess I didn't think about trying the app.config in my test project.

Comment: @Skyrim, I have a test project that I was running that called the code above...that's what I meant.  When I stepped through and debuged my  unit test calling the code above (this code being in a seperate project than my test project), the code in this project (the one the test project is consuming) was not able to find those key/values.  As soon as I put in the strings in the App.Config of my test project, then rant the test, my main project code above found the key/values  So in other words it's not looking for those in its immediate App.Config..but the caller's config

Comment: lol who gave me a -1.  Hilarious.  Slap on my hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings looks in the configuration file of the running program. If this is a library project, you need to add the settings you want to the config file of the host.

Comment: so the host would be my project itself.  For example this project is a wrapper project I've created with classes making api calls to a service reference to a third Party API.  So I placed some strings I need in my wrapper method api calls to be referenced from the App.Config in this project...

Comment: The host would be the program you are running. It could be a web site, a web service, a Windows program or a command line program.

Comment: you were right, yea it's looking at the app.config in my test project which is consuming the project I'm talking about above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any type of .Net application except silverlight the config values are retreived by using [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) in C# and while in silverlight we have to read the config entries with the help of xmlreader. For more checking refer to [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEYNAME"] is Null](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/446cf94d-19ca-48d8-bde4-591686f9368c)

Comment: Thanks, cause I haven't done any Silverlight yet so good to know.

Answer (score 0):

SomeThirdPartyApiUsername should be SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername

---

```
public static string SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername 
{ 
    get { return ConfigUtil.GetAppConfigSetting("SomeThirdPartyApiAuthUsername"); } 
}
```

but your key is

```
"SomeThirdPartyApiUsername"
```

Comment: or the other way around depending on which name you wanted

Comment: sorry just a posting error...I'll update.  The problems still remains.